# TPL task continuation: task is in state Faulted instead of Canceled when cancelled

Tags: c#, concurrency, task, task-parallel-library, continuations

When cancelling the following task, the task is not in state Canceled but Faulted:

```
    private string ReturnString()
    {
        // throw new OperationCanceledException(_cancellationToken);   // This puts task in faulted, not canceled
        Task.Delay(5000, _cancellationToken).Wait(_cancellationToken); // Simulate work (with IO-bound call)
        // throw new OperationCanceledException(_cancellationToken);   // This puts task in faulted, not canceled
        // _cancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();          // This puts task in faulted, not canceled  
        // throw new Exception("Throwing this exception works!");      // This works as expected (faulted)
        return "Ready";
    }

    private void SetReturnValueWithTaskContinuation()
    {
        SynchronizationContext synchronizationContext = SynchronizationContext.Current;
        Task<string> task = Task.Run(() => ReturnString());
        task.ContinueWith(
        antecedent =>
        {
            if (antecedent.Status == TaskStatus.Canceled)
            {
                synchronizationContext.Post(result => _txtResultContinueWith.Text = (string)result, "Cancelled");
            }
            else if (antecedent.Status == TaskStatus.Faulted)
            {
                synchronizationContext.Post(result => _txtResultContinueWith.Text = (string)result, "Exception");
            }
            else
            {
                synchronizationContext.Post(result => _txtResultContinueWith.Text = (string)result, antecedent.Result);
            }
        });
    }
```

I know, that the cancellation token has to be supplied when throwing an OperationCanceled Exception. I know, there are two ways of throwing an OperationCanceled Exception where the ThrowIfCancellationRequested() is the prefered one. And I know, that the cancellation token of the continuation chain should be different than the cancellation token of the task to cancel, otherwise the continuation chain will be canceled too. For the sake of simplification, I only use one cancellation token to cancel the task itself.
But, the task has state "Faulted" and not "Canceled". Is that a bug? If not, than it is a usability issue of the TPL. Can somebody help?

Comment: (Not directly related to your question, but note that you can use `.ContinueWith(..., TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext())` instead of capturing and dispatching to it manually)

Comment: You probably need to pass `_cancellationToken` into `Task.Run`? Currently `Task.Run` sees an Exception (in the form of the `OperationCanceledException`), and puts its `Task` into the Faulted state. If you pass `_cancellationToken` to the `Task.Run`, it'll see that the exception it caught is an `OperationCanceledException` with the same token as the one it was given, and put its `Task` into the Canceled state instead.

Comment: I tried to pass _cancellationToken into Task.Run. Then the continuation chain is cancelled too. It requires two cancellation tokens then: one to cancel the task itself but not the continuation chain and one to cancel the continuation chain. As I stated, I left it out for the sake of simplicity.

Comment: "*I tried to pass _cancellationToken into Task.Run. Then the continuation chain is cancelled too*" -- are you sure about that? I can't repro: https://dotnetfiddle.net/8SEYQr

Comment: Please refer to the following article for details about using the same cancellation token for the continuation chain:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10563214/tpl-cancellation-continuation-never-called-on-cancelled-task

Comment: Does that apply, since you're not passing your CancellationToken to your continuation?

Answer (score 1):

`Task.Run` does want us to provide a cancellation token for proper propagation of the cancellation status, see:

[Faulted vs Canceled task status after CancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24359761/1768303)

This is particularly important if we use the overrides of `Task.Run` that accept `Action`, or `Func<T>` delegate where `T` is anything but `Task`. Without a token, the returned task status will be `Faulted` rather than `Canceled` in this case.

However, if the delegate type is `Func<Task>` or `Func<Task<T>>` (e.g., an `async` lambda), it gets some special treatment by `Task.Run`. The task returned by the delegate gets unwrapped and its cancellation status is properly propagated. So, if we amend your `ReturnString` like below, you'll get the `Canceled` status as expected, and you don't have to pass a token to `Task.Run`:

```
private Task<string> ReturnString()
{
    Task.Delay(5000, _cancellationToken).Wait(_cancellationToken);
    return Task.FromResult("Ready");
}

// ...

Task<string> task = Task.Run(() => ReturnString()); // Canceled status gets propagated
```

If curious about why `Task.Run` works that way, you can dive into its [implementation details](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/mscorlib/a.html#89fc01f3bb88eed9).

Note though, while this behavior has been consistent from when `Task.Run` was introduced in .NET 4.5 through to the current version of .NET Core 3.0, it's **still undocumented and implementation-specific**, so we shouldn't rely upon it. For example, using `Task.Factory.StartNew` instead would still produce `Faulted`:

```
Task<string> task = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => ReturnString(),
     CancellationToken.None, TaskCreationOptions.None, TaskScheduler.Current).Unwrap();
```

Unless your associate a cancellation token, the only time when `Task.Factory.StartNew` would return a `Canceled` task here is when `ReturnString` has been modified to be `async`. Somehow, the compiler-generated `async` state machine plumbing changes the behavior of the `Task` returned by `ReturnString`.

In general, it's always best to provide a cancellation token to `Task.Run` or `Task.Factory.StartNew`. In your case, if this is not possible, you may want to make `ReturnString` an `async` method:

```
private async Task<string> ReturnString()
{
    var task = Task.Run(() => 
    {
        Thread.Sleep(1500); // CPU-bound work
        _cancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
    });

    await task; // Faulted status for this task

    // but the task returned to the caller of ReturnString 
    // will be of Canceled status,
    // thanks to the compiler-generated async plumbing magic

    return "Ready";
}
```

Usually, [doing async-over-sync is not a good idea](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/pfxteam/should-i-expose-asynchronous-wrappers-for-synchronous-methods/), but where `ReturnString` is a private method implementing some GUI logic to offload work to a pool thread, this is might the way to go.

Now, you might only ever need to wrap this with another `Task.Run` if you wanted to take it off the current synchronization context (and if even you do so, the cancellation status will still be correctly propagated):

```
Task<string> task = Task.Run(() => ReturnString());
```

On a side note, a common pattern to not worry about synchronization context is to routinely use `ConfigureAwait` everywhere:

```
await Task.Run(...).ConfigureAwait(continueOnCapturedContext: false);
```

But I myself have stopped using `ConfigureAwait` unconsciously, for the following reason:

[Revisiting Task.ConfigureAwait(continueOnCapturedContext: false)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28410046/1768303)